# How do I put private in front of many variables at once in android studio?

Tags: android-studio, refactoring, private

```
public class Page7 extends Activity {
    ImageView forward ;
    ImageView backward ;
    ImageView mayatnik;
    ImageView pic2 ;
    ImageView pic3 ;
    long milliseconds_per_second = 150 ;

    ArrayList<ImageView> birds ;
    ImageView bird0 ;
    ImageView bird1 ;
    ImageView bird2 ;
    ImageView bird3 ;
    ImageView bird4 ;
    ImageView bird_button ;
    TextView oba, kotenka, zavorozheno, smotreli, na, matnik, chasov, Strelki, chasov2 , doshli, do_, dvenadcat, i, vdrug, neojidano, viglanula, kukushka, i2, prokuk, dve_2, raz;
    TextView ot, ispuga, kotata2, pluh, na2, spinki, kak, smeshno, bilo, Timuru, smotret, na3, nih,on, zalilsa, gromkim, smehom;
    ArrayList<TextView>words ;
    CountDownTimer timer ;
    TextView page ;
    boolean picture_state ;
    int counter ;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
```

I need to put private in front of all fields declared above, i tried refactor->.... but nothing seems to work, also tried to look in the "code" part.

Do you know?

Comment: Great field naming, btw. Why did you choose these exact names for `TextView`s?

Comment: @aga, help me resolve the problem

Answer (score 2):

Android Studio and IntelliJ support having more than one caret in a document, so that if you need to enter the same text in multiple places, you can place a caret at each place and type once to have the text go to all of them. On MacOS with the default keyboard layout, you can hold down Alt+Shift while you click to drop another caret at the click point. If you do this at the beginning of each line you want to change and type "private " once, it will do you what you want.

Comment: hi, i would like to get your attention to this question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35539960/how-to-get-release-build-apk-file-using-proguard, your help would be greatly appreciated